# How to reset counter of primary key in SQL Server provided by Visual Studio in ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

For learning purpose, I am developing one web site. And I have hardly run the website 100 times, but I don't know one of the table's primary key has reached 2012 count. And no way I have inserted even 100 records in total. I am not sure how did that happen. Currently, I have just 1 records in the table but their PK is 2013. I want it to reset to 0. I DO NOT Care about records being deleted as the web site is under development.

Below is the behavior:

This is the VS Debugger output:

[image: Visual Studio Debugger]

[image: Table definition]

You can clearly see I have just one record but PK is 2013

[image: Notice the PK]

Controller Action

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CoverLetter coverLetter, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedCoverLetter)
        {
            var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (uploadedCoverLetter != null && uploadedCoverLetter.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var tempcoverletter = new CoverLetter
                        {
                            FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedCoverLetter.FileName),
                            ContentType = uploadedCoverLetter.ContentType,
                            CoverLetterName = coverLetter.CoverLetterName,
                            CandidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                            datetime = System.DateTime.Now
                        };
                        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(uploadedCoverLetter.InputStream))
                        {
                            tempcoverletter.Content = reader.ReadBytes(uploadedCoverLetter.ContentLength);
                        }
                        _context.CoverLetters.Add(tempcoverletter);
                    }
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CoverLetterCenter");
                }
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke: First answer in the link you mentioned tells to run command `TRUNCATE TABLE Customers`. Where do I need to go in Visual Studio to run this command `TRUNCATE TABLE CoverLetter`. I can can see the server explorer in Visual Studio. But where to type this command and run it? Also, it will just reset the PK right?

Comment: Its a Transact-sql script. Easiest to run in SSL Server Management Studio. But refer also [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833241(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDENTITY columns is keep track and auto increment by SQL Server, I think it has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Run this query on SQL Server

`DBCC CHECKIDENT ('CoverLetters', RESEED, 1)`

Comment: But where to run this query. Can you tell me where I can run this query in My Visual Studio?

Comment: In "Server Explorer" Window
> Data Connections
  > Name of Your DB Connection
    * right click
    * select "Query Window"

Comment: Worked perfectly.. :)